# Call double load more when scroll grid view run to the end

Tags: android, gridview

I want load more data when scroll of gridview run to the end of screen and I used set on scroll listener for it but it call double load more when scroll run to end
My EndScrollGridHome.java

```html
public class EndScrollGridHome implements OnScrollListener {

 private int visibleThreshold = 0;
 private int currentPage = 0;
 private int previousTotal = 1;
 private boolean loading = true;
 private String url;
 private int totalItem = 10;
 ArrayList<Posts> arrData = new ArrayList<Posts>();
 BaseAdapter adapter;
 private Context context;
 
 private Dialog dialog1;
 Activity activiy;
 ArrayList<Posts> listPosts;
 ArrayList<Posts> listPostsGrid;
 ArrayList<Posts> listLoad;
 String name;
 String value;
 private ImageView imgLoad;
 private Animation anim;
 private ListView list_popular;
 private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;
 private boolean mIsScrollingUp;
 private Scrolling sCrolling;


 
 public EndScrollGridHome(ArrayList<Posts> listPostsGrid,
   BaseAdapter adap, Context context, String url,
   Activity activiy) {
  this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
  
  this.adapter = adap;
  this.context = context;
  this.url = url;
  
  this.activiy = activiy;
  this.listPosts = listPosts;
  this.listPostsGrid = listPostsGrid;
 }

 @Override
 public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
   int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
  if (totalItemCount > totalItem) {
   totalItem = totalItemCount;
  }

  if (loading) {
   Log.d("OKKKKK", "" + totalItemCount + " " + visibleItemCount + " "
     + firstVisibleItem + " " + visibleThreshold);

   if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
    loading = false;
    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
    currentPage++;
   }
  }
  if (!loading
    && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)&&firstVisibleItem!=0) {
   Log.d("Load more !",  totalItemCount+ " " +visibleItemCount +" "+firstVisibleItem);
   
   loading = true;

   

  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

 }
}
```

It run very good with listview so I tried to split the value but it is still like that
How to call it only once? please help me
Thank so muck